# How can I connect Dotnet 6 inside Docker?

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I am creating a dotnet 6 webapi app to serve a REST API. I can create the project and run via terminal on Mac and access to http://localhost:5000/swagger/ to see Swagger. The problem comes when I try to run throught Docker running `docker-compose run --rm server`. I cannot access to Swagger and getting an HTTP ERROR 403 on the browser tab. I have commented this line in `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`  in API/Program.cs too.

My folder structure is

```
my-project
 -API/
  - Folder with the webapi template
 -dockerfiles/
  - Dockerfile.dev
 app.sln
 docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
      - '5001:5001'
```

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

WORKDIR /app/API/

RUN dotnet dev-certs https

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["dotnet", "watch", "run"]
```

Output in the console when run `docker-compose run --rm server`

```
watch : Started
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app/API/
```

API/Properties/launchSettins.json

```json
 "profiles": {
    "API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `applicationUrl` to `http://*:5000` in your `API/Properties/launchSettings.json`. I'm not sure if this is the same problem you are having, but I ran into this where it always worked inside the container, but never externally. I think it has to do with `localhost` being resolved to something else when connecting to the docker container, and so the incoming URL doesn't look like `localhost` anymore when it gets to the .NET application. Hopefully this fixes it for you as well.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it doesn't work for me. On any case, I truly appreciate your help.